# Generate x509 public key from RSA private key in Erlang

Tags: erlang, rsa, x509

I'm creating an application in Erlang that given a RSA private key it can return the RSA Public key and the x509 Public key associated to that priv key.

I know I can generate the RSA public key by just getting the modulus and the public exponent from the private key.

```
--from OTP-PUB-KEY.hrl
-record('RSAPrivateKey',{
version, modulus, publicExponent, privateExponent, prime1, prime2, exponent1, exponent2,     coefficient, otherPrimeInfos = asn1_NOVALUE}).

-record('RSAPublicKey',{
modulus, publicExponent}).
```

But how can I generate the x509 public key?

I know this is possible, because my old code written in perl used to do that by calling something like this:

```
$private = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_private_key( $hash_ref->{'private'} );
{rsa  => $private->get_public_key_string(),
 x509 => $private->get_public_key_x509_string()};
```

Does anyone has any idea how to do that?

----- JUST AN UPDATE ----

I have found a solution after spending some time learning about x509 and reading Erlang public_key documentation:

Given I can produce a 'RSAPublicKey' from a 'RSAPrivateKey' by simply getting modulus and publicExponent, my code to generate both keys would look like this:

```
getPublicKeysFromPrivateKey(#'RSAPrivateKey'{modulus = M, publicExponent = PE}) ->
    RSAPub = #'RSAPublicKey'{modulus = M, publicExponent = PE},

    %% Encoding the keys
    RSAPublicKey = public_key:pem_encode([public_key:pem_entry_encode('RSAPublicKey', RSAPub)]),
    X509PublicKey = public_key:pem_encode([public_key:pem_entry_encode('SubjectPublicKeyInfo', RSAPub)]),

    [{rsa, RSAPublicKey},{x509, X509PublicKey}].
```

Which will produce:

```
[{rsa,<<"-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----- \nMIGJAoGBAMU8ZcQ4S+gHDuZd6cEdqbf9l1Hw4fxQrJ455B2kJRUwyKidVbCH2omy\nI0SLNu92"...>>},
 {x509,<<"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDFPGXEOEvoBw7mXenBHam3/ZdR\n8OH8UKye"...>>}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean x509 certificate? Why do you think you need such a thing?

Comment: I really want the x509 public key. This is another format of RASPublicKey, which in 'PEM' format would be a 'BEGIN PUBLIC KEY' instead of 'BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY'.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing would be:

```
public_key(#'RSAPrivateKey'{modulus = Mod, publicExponent = Exp}) ->
    #'RSAPublicKey'{modulus = Mod, publicExponent = Exp}.
```

Which seems to produce a valid record from:

```
public_key(public_key:pem_entry_decode(hd(public_key:pem_decode(element(2, file:read_file("<OTP Src Dir>/lib/public_key/test/public_key_SUITE_data/server_key.pem")))))).
```